# Dealing with the huge number of Boost header files

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-construction

Is there a way to drastically reduce the number of header files needed for Boost?

Ideally, I'm asking the Boost folks to find a way to make their product smaller.  But in the meantime, is there a way to include Boost, but not have several thousand header files to deal with?

Is there a C++ mechanism to "bundle" thousands of header files into a single "package" and just check that single file into source control?

I guess the problem here is source control  Doing a diff, `svn status` and `svn checkout` is so slow with all these files to deal with.

Comment: Only the first check in/out is slow though, correct?  I doubt you are doing significant changes to the boost headers, so once they are downloaded on the first checkout, subsequent checkouts don't have to get updated versions.  This is assuming your source control mechanism is relatively sane.

Comment: In addition to what Chad said, I tend to not check in third party libraries into source control, unless I'm planning on modifying the code myself. Instead, just archive the library, and include build instructions in your project on how to get it to compile.

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with"? I've found that using precompiled header files can be a true livesaver, accelerating a small program compilation from 10+ seconds to a fraction of a second when using Boost.GIL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost offers a tool called [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html). BCP allows you to extract subsets of Boost.

It can also analyze your source tree and extract only the Boost components that your source tree is using.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend putting your third-party libraries in a separate repository. Boost is template heavy, so there is a pretty good reason for them not to bundle their headers. Trying to include bundled Boost headers would move your "wasted" time from version control into your build times. That doesn't really scale. I would refuse to use Boost if you tried to do that to my Boost headers.

Answer (score 1):

[ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) can be a life saver for speeding up preprocessor heavy compilations.

Comment: For Unix-like operating systems only?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to package all in one file (except versioning an archive, but it's not great practice nor practical at all). On a side note, Subversion is known to be slow at checking out thousands of small files such as Boost headers, so maybe you can consider switching to a higher-performance SCM like Git.

You'll be interested in [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html), a Boost tool that analyzes your source and copies the Boost headers you use into a separate directory. This helped a lot to reduce third-party files and was mostly right in my case (I just had to add a few ones to the list).

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked, but here's a way to fix you problem. As I understand it, you are adding the Boost files to your code control repository. Why? They are not part of your project per se; they are not under your *control*.

Here's how I structure my projects such that I don't run into that kind of problem. Everything is added to source control, except the *include* and *lib* folders, as mentioned below. (I only show the relevant parts of my directory tree.)

- /

  - src — includes my own source files and headers
  - ext — external dependencies (such as boost)

    - boost-1-46-1

      - Download.txt — includes link where you can download the correct version from
      - include — this is not added to source control
      - lib — this neither

Comment: "Why? They are not part of your project per se, they are not under your control." There are several reasons to do so. I put external projects under version control to make it easier to distribute to other machines (just to a pull and you get what you need). It also ensures that if I accidentally change any of the files, I can undo those changes. And of course, if I need to fix a bug, it's already under version control.

Comment: Making sure all developers are on the same version of 3rd party libraries is a nightmare if you don't put stuff in revision control.

Comment: @Tom & Nicol: I admit I never worked with a team before and the answer was written from that perspective. Still, wouldn't it be better to have two repositories: one for your code and one for the 3rd party libs?

Comment: @Paul Yes.  It is much better to put them in separate repos, especially in the case of boost.